# How do I combine a paginate method with a model method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my controller I have the following set up

**Controller**

```
if params[:search]
  @beers = Beer.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
else
  @beers = Beer.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

**Model**

The `Beer.search` is coming from my model which has this method defined

```
def self.search(search)
  where("name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end
```

**View**

Lastly, in my view I have this code

```
<%= will_paginate %>
<ul class="beers">
  <%= render @beers %>      
</ul>
<%= will_paginate %>
```

So Im using paginate, but my error that I am getting is "undefined method `total_pages'"

After doing research, this error comes from not setting a page limit, which is not being done in the `params [:search]` if statement. Is there a way to keep my current set up, but also include a paginate part as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set a flag for whether these queries are paginated or not.

```
if params[:search]
    @beers = Beer.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
else
    @beers = Beer.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @paginated = true
end
```

then check if this flag is set.

```
<% if @paginated %>
  <%= will_paginate %>
<% end %>
<ul class="beers">
  <%= render @beers %>
</ul>
<% if @paginated %>
  <%= will_paginate %>
<% end %>
```

Or paginate the search results too `@beers = Beer.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page])`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
if params[:search]
  @beers = Beer.search(params[:search]).paginate(page: params[:page]).order("created_at DESC")
else
  @beers = Beer.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

To refactor your code please do this:

**Controller**

```
@beers = Beer.search(params[:search]).paginate(page: params[:page]).order("created_at DESC")
```

**Model**

```
def self.search(search = nil)
  if search.present?
    where("name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
  else
    all
  end
end
```

I hope this help you.